# using wget to automatically open URLs and save them

Tags: linux, bash, csv, wget

I want to use `wget` to automatically open a URL and save that in `csv` format. Here is the problem:

1- I want to run this command `./mydownload 2011 8 29`

2- `wget` should open the URL `http://d1.website.com/2011/8/29/MonthlyReport.html?format=1`

3- Then save that file to `2011_8_29.csv`

How can I do that with a bash script? also it there are simpler solutions please state them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#/bin/bash

wget --output-document=$1_$2_$3.csv http://d1.website.com/$1/$2/$3/MonthlyReport.html?format=1
```

**Edit**
Try something like

```
wget -qO- http://d1.website.com/$1/$2/$3/MonthlyReport.html?format=1 \
    | sed 's+<br />++g' > $1_$2_$3.csv
```

Comment: that is fine. However in the output file, all line have `<br />`. Isn't there any way to save as plain text?

Comment: ok thanks. may I know what does `s+<br />++g` mean? what does `g` and `s` mean? global and string?

Comment: search and global.  it means search for `<br />` and replace it with nothing (look inside the delimiters e.g. '+') and the g for replacing all the occurrences

Comment: whey `s/<br />/g` doesn't work then? `<br />` will be converted to `>/>`

Comment: because it confuses which '/' is to be replaced with the delimiters, otherwise you need to escape them \/

Comment: so if the pattern contains `/`, sed sould use `+` for delimiter. Right? one more question. Why `+` and `++`? using `++` and `++` give error

Comment: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/10/unix-sed-tutorial-advanced-sed-substitution-examples/